# Are callbacks of the same Node called sequentally in MultiThreadExecutor?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's suppose I have nodes A, B and C on a MultiThreadExecutor with two threads.

Then suppose that the Event Queue has the following events:
Node A Callback1  | Node A Callback1 | Node B Callback 2

From what I understand:

2. The first thread takes the Node A Callback1.
3. Then the second thread takes the next Node A Callback1.

This will mean that callbacks on the same Node should be thread safe when using MultiThreadExecutor, is that true?
Is there a way to guarantee that the callbacks of the same node are executed sequentially or that each node has its own thread?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316539/are-callbacks-of-the-same-node-called-sequentally-in-multithreadexecutor?/) by [Teckel](https://answers.ros.org/users/37289/teckel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2019-02-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> This will mean that callbacks on the same Node should be thread safe when using MultiThreadExecutor, is that true?

Your understanding is correct.

> Is there a way to guarantee that the callbacks of the same node are executed sequentially or that each node has its own thread?

This is what **callback groups** are for. Adding a node to a [MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup (rclpy)](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/be4bc8821404b8ca4b2e1bf25ace755b06856870/rclpy/rclpy/callback_groups.py#L88) ([MutuallyExclusive callback type (rclcpp)](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/3919ab189795fbf47b5427add06f45d8a43f81ce/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp#L47)), will ensure that its callbacks are executed sequentially.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Teckel](https://answers.ros.org/users/37289/teckel/) on 2019-03-04**:
Thank you. You have pointed me in the right direction. Now I am sure that I should correct some mistakes on my project.